# Local Storage edit not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

```
localStorage.setItem('gameState', '{"
grid ":{"
size ":4,"
cells ":[[{"
position ":{"
x ":0,"
y ":0},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":0,"
y ":1},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":0,"
y ":2},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":0,"
y ":3},"
value ":1024}],[{"
position ":{"
x ":1,"
y ":0},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":1,"
y ":1},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":1,"
y ":2},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":1,"
y ":3},"
value ":1024}],[{"
position ":{"
x ":2,"
y ":0},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":2,"
y ":1},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":2,"
y ":2},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":2,"
y ":3},"
value ":1024}],[{"
position ":{"
x ":3,"
y ":0},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":3,"
y ":1},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":3,"
y ":2},"
value ":1024},{"
position ":{"
x ":3,"
y ":3},"
value ":1024}]]},"
score ":272,"
over ":false,"
won ":false,"
keepPlaying ":false}');
```

My script is just a simple one meant to implement into the browser bar of chrome but it returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I have tried setting the local storage to something simple and it works. Can someone tell me what is wrong or rewrite it so it works.

Comment: Run it from a file; you'll see the line number of the error.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax to me..or are you trying to store everything except the first line and the last ) as a string?

Comment: No enters. JavaScript has no multiline bare strings (need `\` at the end of each line or `" +`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, you had wrong indentation as well as some extra spaces and missing commas.

> localStorage.setItem('gameState', 
>   '{"grid":{"size":4,"cells":[[{"position":{"x":0,"y":0},"value": 1024},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}},{"position":{"x":0, "y": 1}{"value":1024}}]]},"score":272,"over":false,"won":false,"keepPlaying ":false}');